# Cannot activate RowDataBound event for ASP.NET Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, gridview, rowdatabound

I am working through an ASP.NET C# tutorial. I have a simple Gridview with the auto-created Edit & Delete Commandfields. So I've converted the Delete command field to a Templatefield and now I am trying to access the RowDataBound event of the Datagrid to add some code.

When I view the Gridview properties and click on the Events, I can see the RowDataBound event, but when I double-click on that event nothing happens. How do I create my event code? (in fact, I can't double-click on any of the events - they are all disabled).

Here is the top section of code for my gridview:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="colorID" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" ShowFooter="True">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <%-- Edit Button --%>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
            <%-- Delete Button --%>
            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                        CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Thanks for your help.
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I create a gridview, the turn-on of edits, deletes, and inserts as commandfields works fine. Also if I immediately convert the delete commandfield to a templatefield before I do anything else, then the RowDataBound event (and all of the other events) are active and I can build codebehind content.

So, for now, something in the tutorial I am using is changing the character of the gridview events. Mostly, I was trying to dialog "Are you sure you want to delete Item XYZ?" as a validating Eval of the row I am deleting. But for now, with too many other things to learn, I'll just live with the stock OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure?'); and move on to something else that's more important.